# how to change tkinter txt widget colour

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a chat server for myself and school mates (i know) and i would like to change the colour of the background in the text widget.  is there anyway i can do this easily? i know the casual`window.configure(bg="blue")`
but is there anyway for the text widget to have a colour? also, can i change the colour of the button or even the text? thanks! heres the code:

```
top = tkinter.Tk()
top.title("Client code chatter!")
messages_frame = tkinter.Frame(top)
my_msg = tkinter.StringVar()  # For the messages to be sent.
my_msg.set("")
scrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(messages_frame)  # To navigate through past 
messages.
# Following will contain the messages.
msg_list = tkinter.Listbox(messages_frame, height=17, width=70, 
yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT, fill=tkinter.Y)
msg_list.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, fill=tkinter.BOTH)
msg_list.pack()
messages_frame.pack()

entry_field = tkinter.Entry(top,  width=65, textvariable=my_msg)
entry_field.bind("<Return>", send)
entry_field.pack()
send_button = tkinter.Button(top, text="Send", command=send)
send_button.pack()
```

Comment: DId you try doing `window.configure(bg="blue")` on the text widget?

Comment: Yeah, it didnt do anything though...

Comment: That's impossible, since that's precisely how you change the background of a text widget. There's  perhaps more you're not telling us. If you showed what you tried we could help you figure it out.

Comment: @BryanOakley I apologise, but i really dont know what i've done wrong, i  do have it sorted now though, thanks:)

Comment: @BryanOakley I was Changing the window, the name of the vaiable, and forgot the actual name of the text widget (Messages_frame)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every widget you create (`Button`, `Frame`, `ListBox`), you can pass keyword arguments to style to widget. This can be a border, a background color, a text color, etc. A full list of these options for the button widget you can see [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm#Tkinter.Button.config-method). For the other widgets, you can select one from [this list](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm). So yes you can set the background color easily:

```
send_button = tkinter.Button(top, text="Send", command=send, bg="blue")
```

Most style options (`background`, `foreground`, etc...) should work for all widgets